# Is there any API that can take location as parameter and will return list of businesses with their "Email"

Tags: api, rest

I am looking for a REST API that will take location as a parameter and will return a list of businesses with their "Email"(not phone number) at that particular location. Free ones are preferred but if there are paid one you can suggest those also.
Thank you!

Comment: What information is included in "location"?

Comment: City name or country name